# RxJS5 - How can I cache the last value of a aggregate stream, without using Subjects and whilst excluding those that have completed?

Tags: stream, publish-subscribe, rxjs, frp, subject

- I want a pubsub system, with producers and consumers of streams, via
  a dataplane layer but without Subjects.
- Many producers can multicast to the same stream name (e.g,
  'filters.add'), and multiple consumers can subscribe to the stream.
- Producers register with a name and stream to create a 'stream of published streams'.
- If a new producer registers with a particular stream name, the
  streams flowing to the consumers are dynamically updated such that the data received is a merging of all currently active published streams with the name requested.
- One producer stream completing should not cause the aggregate stream to complete and is instead excluded (with all consumers updated) when this occurs.
- A consumer getting a stream after a producer registers should receive the last emitted value of that stream (if there has been one to date).

Here is the code I have so far and the tests I wish to satisfy. I can satisfy the base case but not caching, since:

- completed streams are being excluded even though they may have emitted the most recent value;
- `.cache(1)` after `stream.publish().refCount()` repeats entry `4` from the first `Observable`, instead of `8` from the second;
- even with `pluckActiveStreams` commented out, which also doesn't work, I just can't get it to work with any of the approaches commented out...

My questions are:

- how can I implement caching of the aggregated stream? None of the commented out final lines of `relevantStreams$` accomplishes this.
- I think I need to remove completed streams from the aggregate stream received, so that the aggregate stream itself is not (ever) completed. This is (potentially) accomplished with `pluckActiveStreams`, which is based on the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817174/rx-a-zip-like-operator-that-continues-after-one-of-the-streams-ended/35906684#35906684) but still give late-arriving consumers the last emitted value of the stream, even if it may have been from a now-completed stream?

My current implementation already successfully accomplishes this using observables of ReplaySubjects internally as a 'bridge' between producers and consumers. But this way:

1. all producer streams are automatically made hot;
2. the ReplaySubject needs a hack to ensure it never completes if any of the streams multicasting to it do (otherwise it shuts down the stream for all consumers, as explained [here](https://github.com/rxmqjs/rxmq.js/blob/master/src/rx/endlessReplaySubject.js));
3. Once created upon registration of the first producer, a ReplaySubject representing a stream name for a particular group of producers can never again be made cold, disposed if there are no current producers for that name, or re-instantiated with different arguments, as any previously-registered consumers of that stream would then hold an incorrect reference. Consumers instead therefore need a reference to the reactively updated, declarative aggregate of active streams for a particular name.

### Code

```
const publishStream$ = new Subject();

function publishStream(name, stream) {
    // publish streams as connectables to ensure a single source of truth
    // (i.e., don't duplicate server requests)
    publishStream$.next({ name, stream: stream.publish().refCount() });
}

const availableStreams$ = publishStream$
    .startWith([])
    .scan((streams, stream) => {
        console.log('\nadding stream:', stream.name)
        // (this would eventually be state operations to add/remove streams
        // so this doesn't just keep growing)
        return streams.concat(stream)
    })
    .publish();
availableStreams$.connect()

function getStream(name) {

    const relevantStreams$ = availableStreams$
        .do(res => console.log(`\nstream recalculates here for ${name}`))
        .map(streams => streams.filter(streamObj => streamObj.name === name))
        .filter(streams => streams.length)
        .map(streamObjs => streamObjs.map(streamObj => streamObj.stream))
        .map(pluckActiveStreams)
        .switchMap(streams => Observable.merge(...streams))
        // add caching for late subscribers 
        // per https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1541?
        // (none of the approaches below work):
        //.multicast(() => new ReplaySubject()).refCount()
        // .publishReplay(1).refCount()
        //.share().repeat(1).publish()
       //.cache(1)

    return relevantStreams$;

}


function pluckActiveStreams(streams) {
    const activeStreams = new Subject();
    const elements = [];
    const subscriptions = [];

    streams.forEach(stream => {
        var include = true;
        const subscription = stream.subscribe(x => {
            console.log('value', x)
        }, x => {
            console.log('error:', x)
        }, x => {
            console.log('completed', x)
            include = false;
            const i = elements.indexOf(stream);
            if (i > -1) {
                elements.splice(i, 1);
                activeStreams.next(elements.slice());
            }
        });
        if (include) {
            elements.push(stream);
            subscriptions.push(subscription);
        }
    });

    activeStreams.next(elements.slice());

    const pluckedStreams = Observable.using(
        () => new Subscription(() => subscriptions.forEach(x => x.unsubscribe())),
        () => activeStreams
    );
    return pluckedStreams;
}
```

#### Tests

```
        var acc1 = [];
        var acc2 = [];

        // all streams published get publish().refCount() internally
        var obs1 = Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
        var obs2 = Observable.empty();
        var obs3 = Observable.of(5, 6, 7, 8);

        // consumer before publish - will receive values
        var sub1 = dp.getStream('foo').subscribe(function (i) {
            console.log('subscription receives: ', i)
            acc1.push(i);
        });

        var pub1 = dp.publishStream('foo', obs1);
        console.log('end of publishStream1')
        var pub2 = dp.publishStream('foo', obs2);
        console.log('end of publishStream2')
        var pub3 = dp.publishStream('foo', obs3);
        console.log('end of publishStream3')

        // consumer after publish - should receive last cached value
        // from active aggregated stream
        var sub3 = dp.getStream('foo').subscribe(function (i) {
            console.log("\ncached value received (I also don't fire :( ", i)
            acc2.push(i);
        });

        var i = setTimeout(function () {
            expect(acc1).to.deep.equal([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
            expect(acc2).to.deep.equal([8]);
            done();
        }, 10);
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: I thought it was just "so how can I do this?", but I have tried to add a question more specifically and updated the title, thanks!

Comment: what is the rationale for the `without subjects` requirement?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this info, thank you.

Comment: not sure I understand your explanations, as it is quite wordy, and in the end, in those cases a drawing, and some examples of input/outputs would help more than text, but : hot streams are still lazy i.e. you need to start them, you can add a hack similar to the one you showed to replay subjects so it does not complete when it should not, and if you want to have a hot/cold/hot/cold behaviour for an observable, check the `singleInstance` operator (Rxjs v4). In Rxjs v5, I am not sure what operator you would have to use for replay, but `share` in v5 has the behaviour of reconnection you mention

Comment: i.e being hot when subscribed to, cold when no subscribers, and hot again when new subscribers come. In short my recommendation is : use subjects.