# Collecting the currently incomplete observables in a higher-order rxjs observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex

For example, I have an observable that emits a 10-second timer every 5 seconds. I can use scan to create an observable that emits an array of all the inner observables emitted so far:

```
tick = 5000
tock = 1000
timers = Observable.interval(tick).scan( (acc, next) => {
    let timer = Observable.interval(tock).take(10);
    return acc.concat([timer]);
}, []);
```

But what if I want to emit it to emit an array of all "live" timers (i.e. those that haven't called `complete` yet)?

Here's a crappy ascii marble diagram of what I'm thinking of:

```
-A--B-----
  \  \
   \  \
    \  x
     x
 |  |    |
[A][A,B] []
```

Is there a way to do this using the standard operators, or is this just not an idiomatic thing to try to do with rxjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the "active" method described in this answer to achieve what you want:

[Rx: a zip-like operator that continues after one of the streams ended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817174/rx-a-zip-like-operator-that-continues-after-one-of-the-streams-ended/35906684#35906684)